# ClassNotFoundException although class exists and is loaded

Tags: java, reflection, classpath, classloader

I am building a modular application which contains template classes in its core module (executed by the user) and loads implementations for these classes from `.jar` files in a certain directory on every startup.

The loading process of these implementations looks like this:

```
Collection<Class<?>> output = Lists.newArrayList();
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(path);
Enumeration<JarEntry> jarEntries = jarFile.entries();

URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + path + "!/") };
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

while (jarEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
  JarEntry jarEntry = jarEntries.nextElement();
  if(jarEntry == null
          || jarEntry.isDirectory()
          || !jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")){
    continue;
  }

  ...

  int ignoreClass = ".class".length();
  String className = jarEntry.getName().substring(0,jarEntry.getName().length()-ignoreClass);
  className = className.replace('/', '.');

  Class implementationClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);
  Class<?> outputClass = this.loadToClassPath(path, implementationClass);
  output.add(outputClass);
  continue;

}


private Class<?> loadToClassPath(String path, Class toLoad) throws NoSuchMethodException,
      MalformedURLException,
      InvocationTargetException,
      IllegalAccessException,
      ClassNotFoundException {
  URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) KelpApplicationRepository.class.getClassLoader();
  Method addURL = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
  addURL.setAccessible(true);
  addURL.invoke(loader, new File(path).toURI().toURL());
  return loader.loadClass(toLoad.getName());
}
```

It compiles, but I get the following runtime error:

```
[17:51:24 ERROR]: de/pxav/kelp/core/sidebar/version/SidebarVersionTemplate initializing Kelp v0.1-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/pxav/kelp/core/sidebar/version/SidebarVersionTemplate
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at de.pxav.kelp.core.application.inject.VersionBinderModule.implementationsOf(VersionBinderModule.java:214) ~[?:?]
    at de.pxav.kelp.core.application.inject.VersionBinderModule.lambda$configure$1(VersionBinderModule.java:75) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at de.pxav.kelp.core.application.inject.VersionBinderModule.configure(VersionBinderModule.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at de.pxav.kelp.core.KelpPlugin.onLoad(KelpPlugin.java:41) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:297) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:739) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:535) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:641) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:627) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.aO(DedicatedServer.java:412) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:375) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-db6de12-18fbb24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.pxav.kelp.core.sidebar.version.SidebarVersionTemplate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    ... 45 more
```

I am wondering why, because the `.class` file of `SidebarVersionTemplate` exists in the core module. Maybe it has to do with the `extends` keyword in the implementation class? Does this keyword load classes by default in Java?

implementation class:

```
public class SidebarVersion extends SidebarVersionTemplate {
```

template class:

```
public abstract class SidebarVersionTemplate {
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try just referring to the jar file itself? I mean, you are aware that jar files can be on the classpath directly, right? So try `URL[] urls = { new File(path).toURI().toURL() };`

Comment: The javadoc of [`URLClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) says: *This class loader is used to load classes and resources from a search path of URLs referring to both **JAR files** and directories. Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory. Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be opened as needed.* --- The URL you gave ends with `/`, but it is not a directory on the file system.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for the ideas, but they both don't work. The second one (removing the `/` ) of the `URL` causes a `MalformedURLException` because a URL has to contain `!/` in this case. I've tried the other suggestion but the same error appeared. The exception itself is caused by the line `Class implementationClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);` so I think the class loader does not have problems with the URL, but with loading the class itself, although the debugger says that `className` really is the name of the class.

Comment: try `classLoader.getResource( "de/pxav/kelp/core/sidebar/version/SidebarVersionTemplate.class")` to find out whether it can deal with the URL as intended.